# How to add 2 Attributes one after another in MSTR?

Tags: microstrategy

I am new to MSTR and trying to build a new Dossier and i got stuck on the below issue.

I have 2 attributes and 1 metric in my dataset and Attribute 1 has data A, B & C and Attribute 2 has data X, Y, Z. i want dashboard to look like this

Attribute     Metric
A              1
B              2
C              3
X              4
Y              5
Z              6

When i create my result look like below.

Attribute1    Attribute2    Metric
A              X             1
B              y             2
C              z             3

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reformat your results - Attribute Metric A 1 B 2 C 3 X 4 Y 5 Z 6

I think you mean you want to view metrics for the elements for both the attributes appended one below the other.

I'd suggest you create a consolidation / custom group object and add all elements from both your attributes.
And use this consolidation / custom group instead of the attribute on your report.